# Unable to create aws kinesis stream using ansible module...!

Tags: yaml, ansible, boto, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to create aws kinesis stream using ansible and I got some example module snippets from [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/pull/1901/commits/4e1c3a58b376687e4f028e387a5296520372818b)

My modified snippet kinesis.yml is here to create kinesis stream on specific region:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
 #aws region to create kinesis
     region: ap-south-1
  tasks:
    - name: Set up Kinesis Stream with 2 shards and wait for the stream to become ACTIVE
      kinesis_stream:
              name: test-stream
              shards: 2
              wait: yes
              wait_timeout: 600
              region: "{{ region }}"
      register: test_stream
```

I think some where I messud up with the way we can define kinesis module and I got the below error:

```
centos]# ansible-playbook  -vvvv kinesis.yml
    No config file found; using defaults
    ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.
    
    The error appears to have been in '/home/centos/kinesis.yml': line 4, column 7, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
    
    The offending line appears to be:
    
      tasks:
        - name: Set up Kinesis Stream with 2 shards and wait for the stream to become ACTIVE
          ^ here
```

I have configured my aws console access keys with boto.
Please let me know is there a right way to define ansible playbook to create a kinesis on specific aws region.?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I achieved by using aws cli with ansible. On a bit more exploring to ansible, it also supports a command line options. So, we can pass aws cli commands that works with ansible.

Here is my sample module snippet:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    streamName: test-stream
    shardCount: 2
  tasks:
    - name: Create Kinesis Sream
      command: aws kinesis create-stream --stream-name {{streamName}} --shard-count {{shardCount}}
      register: kinesis
```

Using this AWS CLI approach we can quickly add more AWS functions/services to our Ansible playbook.

Answer (score 1):

`kinesis_stream` is in a pull request that hasn't been included yet. That means it isn't part of Ansible. It often takes a long time for a module or revision to actually ship in Ansible (they are fairly dev-unfriendly).

To use that module, you need to put it in your local `library/` folder.

Comment: From where do I get that library. Please share if you have any reference links. Thanks

Comment: [Here it is](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/pull/1901). You probably shouldn't be using it without a higher level of Ansible expertise.

Comment: Yes I am exploring now. Hope I will achieve it in coming days! :) Thanks

Comment: I hope kinesis module will be included soon as a part of ansible. [Ansible Cloud Modules](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_cloud_modules.html)